# Tips on making REST client calls faster

Tags: java, rest, resttemplate, urlconnection

I've been experimenting with both Spring's `RestTemplate` and Java's `URLConnection` to make REST client calls to an external API.  I'm dismayed that looping 100 times doing the same REST GET call (which returns a small JSON response) takes about 60 seconds with `RestTemplate` and about 53 seconds with `URLConnection`.  I'm testing this because my web app needs to make quite a few calls to this external API via HTTP GET, PUT & POST so I'm trying to write these calls to be as efficient as possible.

Is there something I can do to improve the efficiency of either of the code snippets below?  Or is there another library that is considered highly efficient as a REST client?  I would like to use `RestTemplate` but I'm also OK with going more low-level via `URLConnection` if it will mean faster client-side REST calls.

Maybe it's a faulty assumption of mine but I figured that making 100 HTTP GET calls to an endpoint that returns a small JSON response would take no more than 10 seconds.

Here are the methods I've been experimenting with (`credsProvider`, `requestFactory` & `restTemplate` are initialized outside of the method with the thought that "new'ing" these repeatedly might cause performance issues)

```
public static String performGetRestRequest(String host, int port, String user, String pass, String endPoint) throws Exception {
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(host, port),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, pass));
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .build();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpclient);

    return restTemplate.getForObject("http://" + host + ":" + port + endPoint, String.class);
}

public static String performGetRestRequestWithPureJava(String host, int port, String endPoint) throws Exception {
    URLConnection connection = new URL("http://" + host + ":" + port + endPoint).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", CHARSET);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), CHARSET));
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Have you measured how much of that time is spent on the server side?

Comment: restTemplate.getForObject on average is taking about 600 milliseconds and accounts for a total of 59 of the 61 seconds I mentioned in my post

Comment: URLConnection.getInputStream on average takes about 540 milliseconds and accounts for the bulk of the 53 seconds I mentioned

Comment: Seems that those calls are the bottlenecks...what can I replace those with or how can I make them more efficient I guess is the pertinent question...

Comment: `URLConnection::getInputStream()` blocks until the server side makes data available. So before optimizing the client you should check how much time is spent on the server and what your network roundtrip times are.

Comment: Another thing is that you should not create new URLConnection objects over and over again, calling `openConnection()`. Instead re-use the connection you already have open.

Comment: @Ralf - you lead me down the right path...`RestTemplate` is not the issue...it's the server side...you can post something along the lines of "problem could be on the server side..." and I'll accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start optimizing your client, you should make sure that the time is actually spent there. First you need to measure how much time the server takes to come up with the answer to a request. And what are your network roundtrip times? This will give you a more complete picture of where the time goes.

I cannot comment on Spring's REST template as I have never used it. But reading from the stream returned by `URLConnection::getInputStream()` will block until the server side actually sends data. So measuring "client time" for a call to `performGetRestRequestWithPureJava(..)` includes the network roundtrip as well as the time the server takes to come up with the response to the request.

A side note: If you make repeated requests to the same destination, do not repeatedly create new URLConnection instances and call `openConnection()`. Instead re-use a single instance with the connection already open.

Comment: The same sidenote could be said about the `restTemplate` related code. Amongst other purposes, a `HttpClient` is made to automatically reuse open connections whenever possible. Building a new client at each request defeats any chance of benefiting of this advanced behavior. One should assign the `restTemplate` its client object once, and let it work from here (the whole of Spring is pretty much about : "configure it once at startup, then let it be").

Comment: @GPI, sure, it is just that I do not have any practical experience with the Spring template. Feel free to edit/enhance my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using ASyncTask and URLConnection is apparently slower than using other libraries that are out there. Consider using Volley or Retrofit.

Take a look at [this](http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/) article.

Answer (score 0):

Use below library . it is much faster and easier to use

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.asynchttpclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
</dependency>.
```